# Python Multi Threading using Requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a web scraper. I could've just used scrapy but decided to write it from scratch so I can practice.

I've created a scraper that works successfully using requests and BeautifulSoup. It navigates through about 135 pages with 12 items on each, grabs the link and then grabs the information from the link destination. At the end it writes everything in a CSV file. It only grabs strings and it doesn't download any images or anything like that… for now.

Problem? It's quite slow. It takes about 5 secs to grab the everything just from contents of one page so that times 135 is about 11 minutes.

So my question is how do I implement threading in my code so it gets data way faster.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv


def get_actor_dict_from_html(url, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    #There must be a better way to handle this, but let's assign a NULL value to all upcoming variables.
    profileName = profileImage = profileHeight = profileWeight = 'NULL'

    #Let's get the name and image..
    profileName = str.strip(soup.find('h1').get_text())
    profileImage = "http://images.host.com/actors/" + re.findall(r'\d+', url)[0] + "/actor-large.jpg"

    #Now the rest of the stuff..
    try:
        profileHeight = soup.find('a', {"title": "Height"}).get_text()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        profileWeight = soup.find('a', {"title": "Weight"}).get_text()
    except:
        pass

    return {
        'Name': profileName,
        'ImageUrl': profileImage,
        'Height': profileHeight,
        'Weight': profileWeight,
        }


def lotta_downloads():
    output = open("/tmp/export.csv", 'w', newline='')
    wr = csv.DictWriter(output, ['Name','ImageUrl','Height','Weight'], delimiter=',')
    wr.writeheader()

    for i in range(135):
        url = "http://www.host.com/actors/all-actors/name/{}/".format(i)
        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        links = soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "card-image" })

        for a in links:
            for url in a.find_all('a'):
                url = "http://www.host.com" + url['href']
                print(url)
                response = requests.get(url)
                html = response.content
                actor_dict = get_actor_dict_from_html(url, html)
                wr.writerow(actor_dict)
    print('All Done!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lotta_downloads()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you'd better not reinvent the wheel and use something like a `Scrapy` web-framework.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use `gevent` library?

gevent library has `monkey patch` making blocking function to non-blocking function.

Maybe `wait time` of requests is too much and so slow.

So I think that Making request as non-blocking function make your program fast.

On python 2.7.10
example:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all() # Fix import code
import reqeusts

actor_dict_list = []

def worker(url):
    content = requests.get(url).content
    bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
    links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'card-image'})

    for a in links:
        for url in a.find_all('a'):
            response = requests.get(url) # You can also use gevent spawn function on this line
            ...
            actor_dict_list.append(get_actor_dict_from_html(url, html)) # Because of preventing race condition

output = open("/tmp/export.csv", "w", newline='')
wr = csv.DictWriter(output, ['Name', 'ImageUrl', 'Height', 'Weight'], delimiter=',')
wr.writeheader()

urls = ["http://www.host.com/actors/all-actors/name/{}/".format(i) for i in range(135)]
jobs = [gevent.spawn(worker, url) for url in urls]
gevent.joinall(jobs)
for i in actor_dict_list:
    wr.writerow(actor_dict)
```

public gevent document: [doc](http://www.gevent.org/)

P.S.

You must install python-gevent If you have ubuntu OS

`sudo apt-get install python-gevent`

Comment: i'm having trouble figured where I could place this in my code. Does it have to be a function within function? (lotta_downloads)?

Comment: Oh, Sorry. It was my fault. See code again. I've fixed it.